# How to create doodle logo with magnifier lens effect on hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking for creative logo solution and I came up with idea of making magnifier glass effect. For example when user hovers certain area of logo it gets zoomed in with magnifier glass effect. I wasn't able to find a lot of info on this.

But I did manage to find this website which describes how google made its logo for first world fair. This is exactly what I'm looking for, but it only describes logic behind creation of such logo.

http://devlup.com/html5/google-first-worlds-fair-magnifying-glass-doodle-how-did-they-do/1956/

Could anyone help with coding parts of this? I pretty much get the idea of using two images one small one big. But I'm stuck with further steps.

Comment: ... Creative logo solution: http://roxon.in/scripts/parallax/

Comment: @roXon that does not appear to be the same effect that the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Matt I know, it was just an mind-burner. Writing my answer you were faster than me! So ... +1 to you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, there's a [jQuery plugin for that](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-wadda-plugin/).

Comment: the link just goes to a blank page with a 'Google pays me' ad...  - looks like the plugin isn't in development

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the broken link. I do agree that the plugin appears to not be actively developed, though.